# TFS - powershell script to check stderr

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am running a job in TFS. After the job is done I get an output saying TEST OK or ERROR. Now I would like this powershell step in TFS to fail (highlighted in red color) if the console output contains the string ERROR.
Is this possible?

Since the log is only written to STDOUT I need first to copy the logs from stdout to stderr and then check if the string ERROR is found.

1. copy stdout to stderr. Something like "dir > 1>&2"
2. if(stderr.contains("ERROR") => FAIL ON STANDARD ERROR

But I don´t really know how to achieve this in powershell script?

Any input is appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous [logging commands supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) by the build/release system.

As an example,

```
Write-Output "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Whatever Error Message You Want"
```

will write an error to the logging stream.